# Fetching a single value from MySQL database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch a single value (the id) from a mysql database in PHP. I know this can be done in the following way:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email ='" . $email . "'";
$result = $conn->query($q);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row["id"];
```

However, I would think that I could speed up the query by instead of querying the entire row, I would only make a query for the id, which I would do like so:

```
$q = "SELECT 'id' FROM users WHERE email ='" . $email . "'";
$result = $conn->query($q);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row["id"];
```

But for some reason, this returns the string "id", instead of the actual value. I have looked at a couple other similar questions, and the answers that I've tried from those gave the exact same result.

Comment: remove single quotes arround column name . if use single quotes .it consider as string . column name and table name should be enclosed by back ticks

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `id` in the query string

Comment: Use backticks instead of quotes to escape the identifier.

Comment: They should be backticks instead, i.e .\`id\`. 'id' and \`id\` are two very different things. Also you should be [using parametric queries to avoid SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `back-tick instead of single`'`or double`"` quotes

```
$q = "SELECT `id` FROM users WHERE email ='" . $email . "'";
```

Check this for more detail : [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

> But for some reason, this returns the string "id", instead of the actual value.

That's because you're wrapping the column *id* in single quotes. Use backticks instead, like this:

```
$q = "SELECT `id` FROM users WHERE email ='" . $email . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quotes arround column name . if use single quotes .it consider as string . column name and table name should be enclosed by back ticks

```
"SELECT `id` FROM users WHERE email ='" . $email . "'"
```